# How to show multiple queue messeges one after the other in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, client-server

c# (client-server windows form application):

Given that i have multiple messeges coming from the server side that i save in a list/dictionary.

How to show/ popup window messeges one by one ? (e.g for application updates you see a notification). For one messege show popup is not an issue but things get complicated when there are multiple messages.

How to avoid a situation where the second (e.g, last) message overrides/replaces the text of  the first (earlier) message and the user see only the second (last) message text ?

below is my way of doing it:

```
// messages coming from server
// 1 : "test message 1"
// 2 : "test message 2"

// create update-recieved event 

 var e = new UpdateReceivedEventArgs(serverMessages);

// once the update from server is recieved ,  function should update the GUI for each server message, i.e, popup-window will appear for each server message, and user will do some interaction (e.g click ok) and program ends.
```

Any hints ? sample code ?

Comment: You're giving us nothing to do on; what kind of “queue” are you using? What kind of “messages”; those are both very broad terms. How are you displaying them? What do you mean by a message “override” another? Please provide code.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class for handling your messages. When the server passes the messages, have it include a priority or message type as well so that your message handler class knows what should be done with it.

If the message is a notification then it can just show an icon notifying of updates, etc.

If the message is priority then a 'popup box' is required. If another message is received while the popup box is still visible you could append the message to the end of the other message to avoid the end user from clicking through multiple popup boxes.